# Is $f$ Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$?

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $f$ be a continuous function on (a, b], $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)=c\in\mathbb{R}$ and $$g(x)=\begin{cases}f(x)& \text{if}\,  x\in (a,b]\\c&\text{if}\,  x=a\end{cases}$$

Is $f$ Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$? $\int_a^bf(x)dx=\int_a^bg(x)dx$?

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange! Please share your thoughts on this problem. Can you think of a simple example for this situation? What is the answer in that case?

Comment: Hint: Yes, even if you defined $g(x) = -c$ or any other value. The value contributed by the leftmost slice in Riemann sums vanishes as the mesh gets finer.

Comment: What is your definition of $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$?  Are we to interpret this as an improper Riemann integral?

Answer (score 0):

$g$ is continuous function on compact interval is integrable and   since $f=g$ a.e thus $\int_a^bf(x)dx=\int_a^bg(x)dx$.

Comment: But that $f$ doesn't approach a limit as $x \to 0$

Comment: The $1/x$ example is irrelevant given assumptions in OP question.

Comment: So actually, no, it doesn't depend on $f$, as long as $f$ satisfies the stated conditions.

Comment: you are quite right, i didnot notice that  $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)=c\in\mathbb{R}$.